# (C#) OpenXML import xlsx into DataTable with correct column data type

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, openxml, xlsx

I am using OpenXML library to import excelsheet(.xslx) into a DataTable using C#.

The first row of the xlsx contains the column name, so i start adding the column in the DataTable:

```
foreach (Cell cell in row.Descendants<Cell>())
{
    dt.Columns.Add(GetXlsxCellValue(sharedStringTableList, cell));
}
```

Then i loop all the other rows and i fill the DataTable by adding any single row to my DataTable in a similar way with any cell in the current row.

Now, imagine that my excel has two columns like this

[excelExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCGsz.png)

The first row contain the column name, so the first cell has a DataType = string (the text is stored in sharedStringTableList).

All the other rows contains ONLY Number in the first column (and, in excel, the entire column it's also format as "number").

At the end, in my DataTable, the first column has the correct name ("Number") but the column DataType is **STRING**.

The question: how can i create my DataTable with the correct column DataType set in the xlsx at the beginning? 
The method "Columns.Add()" allow you to specify the column dataType, but in the first row all the cell have DataType = string, so i need to check the column DataType in other way.

Thanks in advance,

Andrea

...

Comment: What's your motivation of using OpenXML? Why not just use the old-good Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB provider?

Comment: Hi Kostya, my motivations are the specifications project :) probably I need to use OpenXML to be able to import data without having excel installed on each machine

Comment: Actually, you don't need MS Office or Excel being installed to use the aforementioned OLEDB provider.

Comment: Are you sure Kostya? I just made an attempt on my pc (excel in not installed) and I received this error message: "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."

Comment: You still need the OLDB driver installed but not Excel as I remember. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

Comment: Ok, now i understand! i wrote "Excel" as an example but the specification impose me to not install anything in the machine. So i still have the problem because i can't install this driver. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

There is a library called [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML) that is a friendly wrapper for OpenXML I found much easier to use than straight OpenXML. There is an Enum (XLCellValues) that tells you what the excel data type is. This can be used to help you build the correct data column type.

[Here](https://github.com/TheDev6/ListToExcel/blob/master/src/ExcelHelper/ExcelHelper.cs) is an example of how to navigate and parse the rows and columns into a simple class using closed xml, pretty similar to your example (but for a class instead of data table). There is also a method in that link/example that maps C# sharp types to excel column types that you could use in reverse (XLCellValues enum). It gets more complicated if you don't trust the given excel data type.

If you have a simple target class you are trying to extract out of the excel this [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ListToExcel/) could work out of the box, but I think you want a DataTable output.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, ClosedXML is for creating excel from .net type so it's reduction in types.  What the this post is asking is from handful of Open XML Enum<CellValues> (only handful such as Number to cover all number types)  to  .net type, such as int, double, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You must be looking at the following to set entire column datatype to text:

```
Worksheet.Column(9).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "@";
```